# ¿Como inhabilitar una función del menú mouse desde regedit?

Tags: registro-windows

Tengo poco conocimiento a cerca del Editor de Registro de Windows. 
Se como navegar a través de el y se que lo que busco esta dentro de `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\control panel\Mouse`
Pero no se como inhabilitar una función como tal.

[image: Proof]

Digamos que quiero que ese Checkbox pase de estar de **Enabled=1** a **Enabled=0**.

Trate poniendo algo como "DisableSwapMouseButtons" con valor a 1 pero obviamente no funciono.

Comment: hay algunos cambios en el registro que requieren matar al explorer.exe ( con el taskmanager ) y volver a iniciarlo ( o reiniciar el windows )

Comment: Implemente la linea que mencioné y reinicie el equipo, pero aún así el "checkbox" seguía habilitado.

Comment: ¿Qué versión exacta de Windows usas? ¿Enterprise, Pro, Home?

Comment: Windows 8.1 Pro.